Getting result set in compressed/zip in oracle
I have a SQL query which gives a result set and the size is close to a MB.
How can I compress the result set to reduce size which is consumed by other services.
select ID,product,Name,Desc From Products

There is no BLOB columns involved.
utl_compress.lz_compress is meant for CLOB & BLOB columns.
Is there anything else which can compress or zip the dataset in a location?

What problem does compression solve here?  Potentially, you could fetch the entire result set, write the results to a CLOB, and then compress that CLOB and return it.  I'm hard-pressed to imagine a case where that would solve a problem.  It would force the client to fetch (and then decompress) the entire result set before it could start doing anything with the first row which is generally bad for performance, memory, etc.  But it would technically do what you want.

Convert the output to JSON or XML and then compress the output using GZip compression (or something similar). I am failing to see how this is relevant to Oracle or Oracle SQL Developer as this is something that you would normally implement in the middle tier service that accesses the database and serves the client rather than in the database.

1MB? That's nothing.

As others have noted, a one megabyte result set is tiny.  Depending on how you are connecting, some  types of compression is already done.  Take a look at https://asktom.oracle.com/ords/asktom.search?tag=sqlnetcompression to see more details.
